# Is there a way to analyze and clear out memory from specific python dataframes in Databricks?

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, databricks

I am running a lot of processes on an AWS backed Databricks system that shares resources with other users who are processing queries along side my own. I have run into issues where I run out of memory and the best solution seems to be to restart the cluster, but I can't do that if other people are using it.

I am writing python dataframes that bring in and transforming data from remote SQL tables (not stored in DBFS) and sometimes I do something such as store sql table 1 results as DF1 and SQL table 2 results as DF2 followed by a merge of DF1 and DF2 in python to DF3. It would be helpful to be able to look and see what dataframes are currently being stored in memory. In this case, I would see DF1, DF2, DF3 + any others from other people using the cluster. And then be able to clear DF1 & DF2 out of memory, freeing up resources to process DF3 further.

I know there are some stuff that I could probably do with Spark, like spark.catalog.uncacheTable(df), but I am less familiar with it. I am trying to see if 1) is there a way to see all stored dataframes/variables currently in memory and 2) clear out unwanted dataframes/variables without restarting the cluster?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update: I just found the below code. Does anyone know if this works in databricks too or just on desktop clients? It appears to only show the tables associated with the current workbook that I am in in Databricks, not all the ones on the cluster. More, importantly, does it actually clear the dataframe from memory on the cluster?

```
import gc
del df
gc.collect()
@whos DataFrame
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue you have multiple options.

First of all, you can persist your data using df1.persist(MEMORY_LEVEL), using this operation allow you to specify which level of memory you would like to use. (Memmory, memory and disk, only disk, off_heap and some other levels). You can check  more about the levels using the documentation.

You can also use .cache() to assure your data is saved in cache, but be aware, caching is expensive and is only worth it when you have expensive operations applied to a df and it´s result will be used multiple times.

In both case, and even when you do apply neither, you can use **df.unpersist()** to mark the df as "remove from memory" which will free if from memory faster, or **df.unpersist(True)**, which only returns when the df is fully removed from memory.

Sometimes you dont need to remove it from memory. If you are reading some parquet file ore something like this, spark is smart enought to not overload your memory since it´s reading a READ OPTIMIZED file extension.